# Speech synthesis model creates audio but html page returns previous audio

Tags: python, html, flask, audio, static

I have a trained model for speech synthesis. It creates audio correctly everytime from textarea in html page and saves it static folder. But sometimes when i return audio from folder it brings the older one. It doesnt happen everytime but i couldnt find solution.

**html audio code**

```
{% if my_audio %}
    <audio controls>
        <source src="{{ url_for('static', filename='a.wav') }}" type="audio/wav"/>
    </audio>                
{% endif %}
```

**flask code if you needed**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import inference

app = Flask(__name__)
app.static_folder = 'static'

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/sentez", methods = ["POST"])
def sentez():
    if request.method == "POST":
        metin = request.form["metin"]
        created_audio = inference.create_model(metin)
    return render_template("index.html", my_audio = created_audio)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue arises due to the browser fetching the file from its cache instead of the static folder, after the first run. You need to append a parameter to to the audio file's URL (or query string) that would be unique, so that it will fetch a new copy from the static folder. I suggest appending number of milliseconds elapsed, getTime() method does this in JavaScript.

The JavaScript equivalent for changing the source is as follows:

```
function playAudio() {
   var audioFile = new Audio('./a.wav');
   //URL is ./a.wav
   audioFile.play()
}
```

change this to

```
function playAudio() {
   var audioFile = new Audio('./a.wav?' + new Date().getTime()); 
   //URL becomes something like ./a.wav?1623483193060
   audioFile.play()
}
```

You can find out how to do the same in Flask for modifying the statement

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='a.wav') }}
```

Comment: I will try this out. Thank you.

Comment: @kaganince1 did it solve your problem? You may want to add t= after the ? so that the URL query string becomes a proper key-value pair. 
?t=1623483193060

Comment: I created different name of file every time with random number. That solved my problem.